# Excel bar chart keeps stacking on top of values

Tags: excel, bar-chart, column-chart

I'm trying to get two bars side by side for each variable in a small chart by using both axes. However, even when I put one of the data series on the secondary axis, the two bars continue to sit one on top of the other instead of being side by side. Does anyone know how to solve this? I'm using Excel 2011 on a Mac. Here is the data for the chart.

```
**billing_suggested_plan    avg_project_count   avg_api_calls_per_month**
Growth                       3.13                   143728
Project                      2.54                   124797
Startup                      2.27                   103131
Business                     2.18                   22379
Developer                    1.59                   4433
```

Comment: Are you using a "Stacked" bar chart?

Comment: regular bar chart....but for some reason its literally one bar in front of the other bar....so all of the avg_project_count bars are hidden behind the other data columns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Reason this isn't working is because of the secondary axis. You will have to create an empty series that will hide behind the "API calls" column, which will displace your "Avg Count" column to the side a bit. You will have to play with the formatting to make it look nice, but this will work.

Note: "Empty" and "Avg Count" are on a secondary axis.

[image]